# How to show selected value in multiple select without repitition while editing in PHP

Tags: php, selected

Im using the same form for new entry as well as to edit for training details.In that i have the trainee list which is getting saved in seperate table.So, while editing the particular entry, i have to show the data of selected entry in the form.For that im using `$_GET['act'] =="edit"` to show the value from the database or empty controls for new entry.
In this i have select control,where i can select multiple trainees for the training session. So while editing, im reading the trainee database table and showing the selected trainees.
If i have totally 10 employees ,now i selected 5 employees from the options.
I have to display these 5 employees as selected and another 5 as unselected. But when i do this using below codes, my 'select' controls have options like '5 employees as selected' and all 10 employees as unselected.SO totally 15 options.But i want to have only 10 options.

```
<?php
try {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM enrollment WHERE enrollid = :cid";
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":cid",intval($_GET['cid']));   
   $stmt->execute();
   $enrollresults = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
}

try {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM traineelist WHERE trainingid = :trid";
 $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindValue(":trid",$enrollresults[0]["enrollid"]);  
 $stmt->execute();
 $trlistresult = $stmt->fetchAll();

} 
catch (Exception $ex) 
{  echo $ex->getMessage(); }

try {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
 $stmt = $EMPDB->prepare($sql);                
 $stmt->execute();
 $empresult = $stmt->fetchAll();

} 
catch (Exception $ex) 
{  echo $ex->getMessage(); }    

?>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="tr" class="control-label col-md-2">Trainee</label>      
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                  <select id="trainee" name="tr[]"  multiple="multiple">              
                 <?php           
                 if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=="edit")
                  { ?>
                      <?php foreach($trlistresult as $row1){ ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row1["trainee"]?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row1["trainee"]?></option>
                      <?php  } ?>
                     <?php foreach($empresult as $row){ ?>
                    <option><?php echo $row['first_name']?></option>
                  <?php  } ?>

                <?php
                  }          
                  else
                  {
                     foreach($empresult as $row){ ?>
                    <option><?php echo $row['first_name']?></option>
                    <?php } }?>   

                </select>       
            </div>
        </div>

I want like, it shows the default options with the selected value.
```

For ex:
Status :  Active , InActive - if i select 'active' in the from, while editing the 'Status' control shows like Active(selected),Active,InActive. How to avoid this duplications?

Comment: elaborate more what you want?

Comment: Which variable contains your values while editing?

Comment: Just common it $empresult foreach loop no need for else part as its same in both.

Comment: Is `$row1["trainee"]` having same value as `$row['first_name']`?

Comment: Yes,in employee table,i have the name as 'first_name' and in traineelist table i have the employee names in 'trainee' column. So both have the name of the employee. First,only have selected..Second, all employees

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare array of value of `$row1["trainee"]`. Then replace your code

```
<?php           
if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=="edit")
{ ?>
   <?php foreach($trlistresult as $row1){ ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row1["trainee"]?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $row1["trainee"]?></option>
   <?php  } ?>
   <?php foreach($empresult as $row){ ?>
   <option><?php echo $row['first_name']?></option>
   <?php  }
} ?>
```

With :

```
if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=="edit")
{
    foreach($empresult as $row){ 
        if(in_array($row['first_name'], $trlistResultArray)) $selected = "selected";
        else  $selected = "";
        ?>
        <option <?php echo $selected; ?> ><?php echo $row['first_name']?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
```

If your name from `$empresult` is in array of trainee then set it selected.

Hop this helps!

Comment: nothing is selected. When i print $trlist, it shows " Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set: Array ( [0] => Array ( [trainee] => aaaa) [1] => Array ( [trainee] => bbbb) [2] => Array ( [trainee] => cccc) )  " but nothing selected below. SO i changed as  <option <?php selected = "echo $selected; ?>" ><?php echo $row['first_name']?></option> ..now all options are selected.

Comment: I used $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);  for both trainee and employee table. So,these two arrays are easy to compare and now it works.